# Get non-static methods from a class instead of an instance

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a JS library.

Somewhere the user passes a **class** reference (not an instance!) to one of my factory objects. Now, i want to check that this class implements a certain interface.

If i had an instance i could easily check that it contains the interface's methods, however, I have a class and no knowledge how to instantiate it. Is there still a way to check (at runtime) if the class implements the required methods?

Currently, i force the user to pass an instance of the class, which is somewhat annoying since I only need the class.

Comment: `typeof SomeClass.prototype.someMethod === 'function'`. Of course that only works the methods are actually defined on the prototype and not created inside the constructor.

Comment: @FelixKling Exactly what i was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes are more or less just syntactic sugar for constructor functions. As such, class methods are properties of the `prototype` property of the constructor. So you can do

```
typeof SomeClass.prototype.someMethod === 'function'
```

Of course that only works if the methods are actually defined as "class methods" and not created inside the constructor.